# localstorage not working properly for extJS5.1 treestore?

Tags: tree, local-storage, store, extjs5

I am using ExtJS5.1 treestore along with local storage. I am trying to set records into treestore dynamically using:

```
store.setRoot({
expanded: true,
children: [
    { id: '2', leaf: false, expanded: true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'2',TITEL:'pank211', parentid:'root',  children:
         [
             { id: '3', leaf: false, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'3',TITEL:'pank311', parentid:'2',
                children:
                 [
                    { id: '31', leaf: true, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'31',TITEL:'pank3111' },
                    { id: '32', leaf: true, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'32',TITEL:'pank3112'}
                 ]
            },
            { id: '4', leaf: false, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'4',TITEL:'pank411', parentid:'2',
               children:
                 [
                    { id: '41', leaf: true, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'41',TITEL:'pank4111' },
                    { id: '42', leaf: true, expanded:true, IDN_PLANTEKST:'42',TITEL:'pank4112'}
                 ]

            }
         ]
    }
]
});
store.sync();
```

After sync, local storage showing only 4 records which are inner leaf nodes. Showing only ID = 31,32,41,42

Seems its storing only leaf:true nodes, But I am expecting all records should be saved into local storage.

Please help.